# 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded after switching to multi-primary topology in MySQL InnoDB Cluster

Tags: mysql, clustering, mysql-cluster, mysql-innodb-cluster

I have set up an InnoDB cluster using MySQL (version 8.0.23) Shell. I added three nodes to my cluster. At first, my topology was a single-primary topology where I had one master node and two slave nodes. The problem with this topology was that whenever a failure happened (I voluntarily switched off one of the servers), the master node was not switched to another available node. And when I switched off two nodes, the third node remained in read-only mode which means that my application was down.

So, I decided to switch to a multi-primary topology to avoid the read-only problem which could make me lose purchases and money. But now I get `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded;` almost all the time.

I have no idea what the problem is. I increased `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` to 900 seconds and nothing changed. I thought maybe my MySQL router is not working properly? Could it be a firewall problem? I have already allowed 6603,60330 and 66031 through my firewall. I am not sure. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Physically how far apart are the servers?  `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` -- does it snow any issues?  Raising that wait_timeout merely causes extra problems; don't do it.  Show us the SQL statements in the transaction.

Comment: @RickJames They're in the same city. So, maybe 30 kilometers at maximum. ``SHOW SLAVE STATUS`` returns empty. Is that normal?

Comment: @RickJames As for the SQL statements, there are too many. Almost every SQL statement fails. Even simple insert statements. I mean it's not limited to only complex queries where several tables are joined. Even a very basic insert statement fails.